# Linkedin - Getting empty elements while retrieving company posts using ugcposts api

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to retrieve latest 3 linkedin posts of my company display in my company's webpage.

I do have the following rights for my Bearer token.

openid
profile
email
r_organization_social
r_basicprofile
r_organization_admin
rw_organization_admin
w_member_social

But my request:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?oauth2_access_token=*accessToken*&q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A*myOrganisationId*)&count=3

returns:

{
"paging": {
"start": 0,
"count": 3,
"links": [
{
"type": "application/json",
"rel": "next",
"href": "/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&oauth2_access_token=*accessToken*&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A*myOrganisationId*)&count=3"
}
],
"total": 96
},
"elements": []
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get posts with this endpoint

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn:li:organization:(your company id)&isDsc=false&q=author&count=3

But you're using an old endpoint. My example requires to add the version in the header.

Comment: Thankyou Venyx. 

I am able to get posts using this endpoint. 


https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn:li:organization:(your_company_id)&q=author&count=3

I have add header "LinkedIn-Version : 202304"